# Error invalid user define conversion

Tags: c++, io, compiler-errors

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if(argc != 3)
    cout<< "Error! Not enough file!"<<endl;
char** words = new char* [10];
char** page = new char* [10];
string line;
char* key = "<-1>";
ifstream input (argv[1]);
while(strcmp(std::getline(input, line), key) != 0)
{

}
return 0;
}
```

So when I tried to run this(**of course it is not finished**). The compiler keeps giving me the error that says

`/home/ds/DataStructuresRepo/Project2/untitled/main.cpp:17: error: invalid user-defined conversion from 'std::basic_istream<char>' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]
     while(strcmp(std::getline(input, line), key) != 0)
                                                ^`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why not read the documentation of `std::getline`?

Comment: `strcmp` can't compare the 2 different inputs you've given it. One is a `std::basic_istream<char>` returned from `std::getline()` and the other is a `const char*` (`key`). I think you actually want to be comparing `line` with `key`, and possibly make `key` a `string` type too.

Answer (score 1):

[`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) returns a `std::basic_istream&`. It writes what it reads into the `line` you're passing in. [`strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp) takes two `const char*`s. You cannot just pass the result of the first into the second - those types aren't convertible (hence the error about no conversion from `std::basic_istream<char>` to `const char*`).

Since you're getting a `std::string` anyway, you can just use it's `operator==` directly:

```
while (std::getline(input, line) && line != key)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing wrong is that you're passing an `istream` (the return value of `getline`) to `strcmp` which expects a `char*`.